# How to catch change in the focus of editor - TextEditor?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I create new editor that extend from TextEditor

```
 public class RDLEditor extends TextEditor {
 }
```

When I launch my program and press on the file ( file1) a new Editor is created.( like in java editor)

When I press on another file (file2) a new file is created.( in new tab )

Now I have two files that are exist as tabs ( file1,file2).

I want to add some logic when I change the focus of one file to another file.

Which event from TextEditor I can catch for the change of the focus ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `org.eclipse.ui.IPartListener` to listen for parts becoming active.

Set this up with something like:

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().addPartListener(listener);
```

among other methods the part listener has:

```
public void partActivated(IWorkbenchPart part)
```

which will be called when any part is activated. You will need to check the `part` parameter matches your editor instances.